# ARIMA usage for n rows

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` as follows. This is the original `DF`:

```
Min1 Min2 Min3 | Min4 Min5
1.05 1.01 0.99 |  x    x
1.01 0.99 1.05 |  x    x
0.99 1.05 1.01 |  x    x
```

`Min4` and `Min5` here are predicted values for each stock.I have like 100k of rows and hundreds of columns. Each row represents returns over some period (column) for particular stock (in original file each row has own ID and number of other parameters, which were removed here to make analysis easier to perform). I'd like to build up an ARIMA model for each stock (e.g. for each row) and predict n values ahead (`x` for `Min4` and `Min5` in example here) for that particular stock.

So, I need help with getting everything under a loop or something like that. Currently, I use code like:

```
Y <- DF[1,]
arima1 <- arima(Y, order = c(1,0,1))
pred1 <- predict(arima1 , n.ahead=2)
pred2 <- as.data.frame(pred1$pred)
```

Predicted values are needed to be written to some new `DF` to be used later.

Comment: You can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`

Comment: Will new predicted values (for row 1,2,...,n) be written in DF without overwriting each other? E.g. apply will create nrow vectors in new DF?

Comment: If the example dataset have only 3 columns, and the last 2 are shown for our understanding, `t(do.call(cbind, apply(DF, 1, FUN= function(Y){
 arima1 <- arima(Y, order = c(1,0,1));
 pred1 <- predict(arima1 , n.ahead=2);
 pred2 <- as.data.frame(pred1$pred)
 })))`

Comment: @akrun you'll most likely not need the `do.call(cbind(..` call

Comment: @PierreLafortune  Yes, I also thought so.  The `pred2` part if it is `vector` should make things easier, but I was following the OP's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `apply` wrap is transposed it is coerced to `matrix` class. From there you can create a data frame that can be appended when needed:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(Y) {
  arima1 <- arima(Y, order = c(1,0,1))
  predict(arima1 , n.ahead=2)$pred
  }
)))
#          V1       V2
# 1 1.0308173 1.015321
# 2 0.9789147 1.031609
# 3 1.0345989 1.015456
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me a lot.